# How can I replace one linux distro (Ubuntu 19.04) with another linux distro (Manjaro)?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall, 19.04

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 in UEFI mode alongside Windows 10. I have same root and home directory which is almost 100Gb. I am not satisfied with Ubuntu hence I want ti migrate to Manjaro without losing any data.

Can I migrate from one linux distribution to another linux distribution?  If so, how can I do that alongside windows without loosing any data?

Comment: It would depend on the options provided by the second distro during installation. Since the second distro in your case is a non-Ubuntu distro, we cannot help you with it.

Comment: It would be best to backup or copy data to another hard drive or partition.  Installing over is one of the best easy ways of losing data.

Comment: "Can I migrate from one linux distribution to another linux distribution?" we only support Ubuntu and within Ubuntu you can install ANY of the desktops we offer without re-installing. REGARDLESS of what you do: you need to make a backup.

Comment: Thank you guys for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Can I migrate from one Linux distribution to another Linux distribution?
**Data, yes; applications, no.** Applications will require reinstallation in Manjaro because it is an Arch-based distro, not a Debian-based distro.

If so, how can I do that alongside Windows without losing any data?
**Ask this question in** [http://unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com) **which is for *buntu and also non-*buntu Linux**, or [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com) which accepts questions about *buntu, Linux, UNIX, Windows, MacOS, and even CP/M.